# insert_many not working when adding one more case

Tags: mongodb, collections, vagrant

I used the following code to insert `tab0011.json` into `portal_db.acs`:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json

client = MongoClient()
db = client.portal_db

db.acs.drop()
acs = db.acs

data_acs = json.load(open('/vagrant/data/tab0011.json', 'r'))

result_acs = acs.insert_many(data_acs)
```

The code has stored the tab0011.json data correclty. However, I tried the following code to insert `tab0011.json` into `portal_db.acs` and `tab0007.json` into `portal_db.tab0007`. Both collections were created but with none inside, i.e., empty:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json

client = MongoClient()
db = client.portal_db

db.acs.drop()
acs = db.acs

db.tab0007.drop()
tab0007 = db.tab0007

data_acs = json.load(open('/vagrant/data/tab0011.json', 'r'))
data_tab0007 = json.load(open('/vagrant/data/tab0007.json', 'r'))

result_acs = acs.insert_many(data_acs)
result_tab0007 = tab0007.insert_many(data_tab0007)
```

Not quite sure why.

Comment: Is pymongo returning an error? if yes, please paste the stack-trace. Could you add the values stored inside **data_acs** variable in the example?

Comment: it is not returning error. When I tried `db.acs.find()` on the first case (adding just one collection), mongo has shown all the data inside the collection. Unfortunately, on the second case (adding two collections using same script), the same query returns nothing at all, such as the collection was empty.

Comment: could you share some sample dummy data for the same? Something that shows how the ata is stored in the json files.

Comment: {
 "var0001": 504,
"var0003": 3,
"var0004": 2,
"var0005": 10,
"var0006": [ 2, 1 ],
"var0007": 1,
"var0008": "S",
"var0009": 100000512,
"var0011": "2017-02-20",
"var0012": "2018-02-07",
"var0013": "2017-10-04",
"var0014": 2018,
"var0015": [ 100026497, 100037540 ],
"var0017": null,
"var0018": null,
"var0019": null,
"var0021": [ 141501, 2051700, 4623106, 4683400, 7210000 ] 
}

Comment: So is it something like this: [{"var0001": 504, "var0003": 3, "var0004": 2, "var0005": 10, "var0006": [ 2, 1 ], "var0007": 1, "var0008": "S", "var0009": 100000512, "var0011": "2017-02-20", "var0012": "2018-02-07", "var0013": "2017-10-04", "var0014": 2018, "var0015": [ 100026497, 100037540 ], "var0017": null, "var0018": null, "var0019": null, "var0021": [ 141501, 2051700, 4623106, 4683400, 7210000 ]},
{"var0001": 504, "var0003": 3, "var0004": 2, "var0005": 10, "var0006": [ 2, 1 ], "var0007": 1, "var0008": "S", "var0009": 100000512, "var0011": "2017-02-20", "var0012": "2018-02-07"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file extension is `.json` I am able to read the data via the methods used in your code and insert them into collections in the same database. I can see the data that I used in both the respective collections

Maybe you can try doing it this way:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json

client = MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017)
db = client["portal_db"]

acs = db.get_collection("acs")

tab0007 = db.get_collection("tab0007")

db.drop_collection("acs")
db.drop_collection("tab0007")

data_acs = json.load(open('/vagrant/data/tab0011.json', 'r'))
data_tab0007 = json.load(open('/vagrant/data/tab0007.json', 'r'))

acs_inserts = acs.insert_many(data_acs)
tab_inserts = tab0007.insert_many(data_tab0007)

print(acs_insert.inserted_ids)
print(tab_inserts.inserted_ids)
```

The last two lines would print the ObjectIds of the Documents inserted.